# Hide all marker popups on map android

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have mapView with many custom overlays. Is there some method for mapView object which will clear all popups from map (not markers)?

Answer (score 0):

Since the Google Maps add-on for Android has no concept of "popups", and therefore you put the "popups" there yourself, you will have to ask yourself how you added them, so you can figure out how to remove them.